# Rotate a random image among ten in Kivy

Tags: python, image, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a game in which the user must detect the image that is different from the others. I have ten images in the .kv and I need to create a loop, in which I assign some kind of change (I can think of rotating the image 90 degrees) to one of the 10 images, randomly and when clicking on it, go to the next level, which will be the same exercise but with the change in another of the images. A loop of three repetitions would be nice.

*.kv

```
<ContainerCaza>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'data/img/fondobosque.jpg'
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Ahora debes localizar al intruso entre estas imágenes. ¡Fíjate bien, una de las imágenes es distinta!'
            size_hint_y: None
            text_size: self.width, None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            padding: (20,15)
            font_size: 25
            color: (.66, .38, .14, 1)
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    source: 'data/img/texturacuaderno.png'
        
        GridLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            cols: 5
            spacing: '40dp'
            size_hint: 0.7, 0.7
            #height: self.minimum_height
            
            ToggleButton:
                id: 1
                text: '1'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza01
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.16, "center_y": 0.3}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                
            ToggleButton:
                id: 2
                text: '2'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza02
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.32, "center_y": 0.3}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                   
            ToggleButton:
                id: 3
                text: '3'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza03
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.48, "center_y": 0.3}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                  
            ToggleButton:
                id: 4
                text: '4'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza04
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.64, "center_y": 0.3}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                
            ToggleButton:
                id: 5
                text: '5'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza05
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.3}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                
            ToggleButton:
                id: 6
                text: '6'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza06
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.16, "center_y": 0.7}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
    
            ToggleButton:
                id: 7
                text: '7'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza07
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.32, "center_y": 0.7}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
    
            ToggleButton:
                id: 8
                text: '8'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza08
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.48, "center_y": 0.7}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
    
            ToggleButton:
                id: 9
                text: '9'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza09
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.64, "center_y": 0.7}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
    
            ToggleButton:
                id: 10
                text: '10'
                group: 'g1'
                id: caza10
                background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.7}
                Image:
                    source: "data/img/letra_d/dragon.png"
                    y: self.parent.y
                    x: self.parent.x
                    size: self.parent.size
                    # allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: False
                        
        Button:
            size_hint:.06, 0.1
            text: "Volver al menú"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
```

*.py

```
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
__all__ = ('Caza')

import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import random

#Builder.load_file('caza.kv')

class ContainerCaza(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerCaza, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
class CazaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        #Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
        return ContainerCaza()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    CazaApp().run()
```

Comment: Use a Rotate canvas instruction.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how I can do it, how do I access to change the canvas of the buttons. I am new to python and kivy